# Which Linux header(s) to remove?

Tags: inode

I have run out of inodes (`IUse% = 100%`) and when I run the command from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387415/2156453) answer, `/usr/src` contains the largest number of files (`linux-headers*`).  Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33562735/2156453) answer, I want to remove the old `linux-headers` but I am confused as to which are the oldest/unused.

The contents of `/usr/src/linux-headers*` is:

```
linux-headers-3.13.0-24
linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-33
linux-headers-3.13.0-33-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-34
linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-37
linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-39
linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
<snip>
linux-headers-3.13.0-112
linux-headers-3.13.0-112-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-113
linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic
```

`uname -r` gives `3.13.0-34-generic`

Which headers can I safely delete (using `sudo rm -rf /usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-x*`)?

If I am running `3.13.0-34`, are `3.13.0-37` through `3.13.0-113` newer or am I misunderstanding the number sequence?

Comment: Check the date on the files.

Comment: Using ls -l11 /usr/src gives linux-headers-3.13.0-113-generic and linux-headers-3.13.0-113 as the most recent.  But does that mean I am using that version given uname -r gives 3.13.0-34-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get a definite answer on which linux-headers are safe to remove, so I took an educated gamble and decided, given that I am running   **3.13.0-33-generic** and **3.13.0-34-generic** and **3.13.0-113-generic** is the most recent, the other linux-headers are candidates for toasting.

I `sudo mv` **linux-headers-3.13.0-70*** through **linux-headers-3.13.0-79*** to another partition.  That freed up enough inodes down to about 90% usage.

Then `sudo apt-get purge` linux-headers-3.13.0-37* through to linux-headers-3.13.0-49* and that freed up a lot more inodes.  I could then continue my install (ironically the latest kernel).  I rebooted and all appears well.

Then `sudo mv` **linux-headers-3.13.0-70*** through **linux-headers-3.13.0-79*** back to `/usr/src` and did the same `sudo apt-get purge` as above.

During both lots of the `purge` I got the warning:

```
dpkg: warning: while removing linux-headers-3.13.0-70-generic, directory '/lib/modules/3.13.0-70-generic' not empty so not removed
```

which I suspect is relevant to VirtualBox and so hopefully is not a drama in the future when VirtualBox updates...

Footnote: Found a bug [report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1089195) with respect to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Don't rm -rf the headers; remove headers by the package name; for example, using `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.13.0-24`

You can generally remove headers on kernels that you are not using. You should however be running the latest kernel, that is, the one with the highest number, in your case that would be 3.13.0-113-generic.  Perhaps re-running `sudo update-grub` will ensure that the latest kernel is the first one being booted.

Comment: I tried sudo update-grub (and update-grub2) and I see two kernels: 3.13.0-33-generic and 3.13.0-34-generic.  No mention of 3.13.0-113-generic.  So am I running 113 or 34?  Also I am unable to run apt-get as I am out of disk space, so I think all I can do is rm -rf.

Comment: ls /boot should show if you have a  vmlinuz for 3.13.0-113  - if not, perhaps you may need to re-install it using something like;  sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.13.0-113-generic

Comment: Nope, no 113, just 33/34.  Am unable to run any apt-get command - out of disk space!

Comment: Ah, that's not so good. I suspect you may need to find some large files and remove them, e.g.  top 100 largest files:   sudo find / -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -100

Comment: This problem occurs on my root partition, so I'm not sure what is safe to delete; besides I assume I'd have to use apt-get to remove stuff anyway...and I can't run apt-get!  With regard to the headers, I thought about moving one (or more) to another partition so I can then run apt-get to remove other headers.  Do you know if the headers which are not 33/34.113 are being used (and so are safe for moving and eventual apt-get remove/purge)?